# Keycloak causes loops in react application after I have just login on keycloak auth pag. Infinite Loop when redirect after login

Tags: reactjs, loops, keycloak, infinite

I am using `@react-keycloak/web` for React app securing using keycloak.
I have recently started using KeyCloak with React. My KeyCloak Docker is running on Port 8080 and my React application is running on 3000.

When I try to login, the address bar starts to jump and some different tokens appear in url.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from "@react-keycloak/web";
import keycloak from "./Keycloak"
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import WelcomePage from "./pages/Homepage";
import SecuredPage from "./pages/Securedpage";
import PrivateRoute from "./helpers/PrivateRoute";

function App() {
 return (
   <div>
     <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak}>
       <Nav />
       <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>
           <Route exact path="/" element={<WelcomePage />} />
           <Route path="/secured" element={<PrivateRoute>
                                            <SecuredPage />
                                          </PrivateRoute>} />
         </Routes>
       </BrowserRouter>
       </ReactKeycloakProvider>
   </div>
 );
}
export default App;
```

Nav.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web";

const Nav = () => {
 const { keycloak, initialized } = useKeycloak();

 return (
   <div>
     <div className="top-0 w-full flex flex-wrap">
       <section className="x-auto">
         <nav className="flex justify-between bg-gray-200 text-blue-800 w-screen">
           <div className="px-5 xl:px-12 py-6 flex w-full items-center">
             <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold font-heading">
               Keycloak React AUTH.
             </h1>
             <ul className="hidden md:flex px-4 mx-auto font-semibold font-heading space-x-12">
               <li>
                 <a className="hover:text-blue-800" href="/">
                   Home
                 </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a className="hover:text-blue-800" href="/secured">
                   Secured Page
                 </a>
               </li>
             </ul>
             <div className="hidden xl:flex items-center space-x-5">
               <div className="hover:text-gray-200">
                 {!keycloak.authenticated && (
                   <button
                     type="button"
                     className="text-blue-800"
                     onClick={() => keycloak.login()}
                   >
                     Login
                   </button>
                 )}

                 {!!keycloak.authenticated && (
                   <button
                     type="button"
                     className="text-blue-800"
                     onClick={() => keycloak.logout()}
                   >
                     Logout ({keycloak.tokenParsed.preferred_username})
                   </button>
                 )}
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </nav>
       </section>
     </div>
   </div>
 );
};

export default Nav;
```

Keycloak.js

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";
const keycloak = new Keycloak({
 url: "http://localhost:8080/auth",
 realm: "keycloak-react-auth",
 clientId: "React-auth",
});

export default keycloak;
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the issue you are facing is discussed and answered here: https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak/issues/93

Removing `<React.StrictMode>` from index.js should fix it for now. If you wish to retain strict mode, place StrictMode inside `ReactKeycloakProvider`.

Answer (score 7):

Removing `<React.StrictMode>` would not solve the problem.

The issue is linked to how React-keycloak verifies the issued token hasn't been revoked.For that is tries to load and verify a specific i-frame that is blocked by most modern browsers.

To fix the issue you have two options:

- use onLoad: "check-sso" , silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + "/silent-check-sso.html",
- use checkLoginIframe:false (Although this option is more radical)
  The code in your App.js would look like this:

```
   

     import React from "react";
        import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from "@react-keycloak/web";
        import keycloak from "./Keycloak"
        import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
        import Nav from "./components/Nav";
        import WelcomePage from "./pages/Homepage";
        import SecuredPage from "./pages/Securedpage";
        import PrivateRoute from "./helpers/PrivateRoute";
    
        function App() {
         return (
           <div>
             <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak} initOptions={{
          checkLoginIframe: false,
            }}>
           <Nav />
               <BrowserRouter>
             <Routes>
               <Route exact path="/" element={<WelcomePage />} />
               <Route path="/secured" element={<PrivateRoute>
                                                <SecuredPage />
                                              </PrivateRoute>} />
             </Routes>
           </BrowserRouter>
           </ReactKeycloakProvider>
       </div>
     );
    }
    export default App;
```

This would make your auth work on all browsers.

Comment: @Mockstar Issa - use onLoad: "check-sso" , silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + "/silent-check-sso.html",
Where to use this?

Comment: Hello You can pass it as as values to your initOptions as props to the ReactKeycloakProvider

Comment: Used this advice on keycloak-js and worked just fine! Thank you very much




const authenticated = await keycloak.init({
            onLoad: 'check-sso',
            silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + "/silent-check-sso.html"
        });